# Using .ts extension in import (like deno) in node

Tags: node.js, typescript, deno

I'm looking for a way to include the `.ts` extension in typescript `import` statements then execute it in node using something like `ts-node`. I'm also looking for a way to have the `.ts` extension be valid within VSCode and not throw an error.

My goal would be able to run something like this in both `ts-node` and `deno`

```js
import alpha from './alpha.ts'
import beta from './beta.ts'

console.log({alpha, beta})
```

I was hoping the combination of (1) the plugin [deno_ls_plugin](https://github.com/kitsonk/deno_ls_plugin/tree/c5ed4d532a7154e1c40d991b0aef3f03f89add06) mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27481#issuecomment-645526305) and (2) `tsconfig-paths` would work, something like:

This `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "./*": ["./*"],
      "../*": ["../*"],
    },
    "plugins": [{ "name": "deno_ls_plugin" }]
  }
}
```

And run using this to run:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./merge.ts
```

This doesn't work.

In an ideal world the differences between typescript code and deno would be remedied in a single register, something like `ts-node -r ts-deno/register ./merge.ts`.

I'm essentially looking for a ways of transforming deno-compatible-typescript to node-compatible-javascript. The main issue is that deno-compatible-typescript isn't even compatible with node-compatible-*typescript*.

The main compatibility issues being:

1. ts extensions in imports
2. top-level await
3. url imports
4. `Deno` global (needs shim like [`YounGoat/nodejs.deno`](https://github.com/YounGoat/nodejs.deno))

Comment: There's a post I came across here, that's open with some discussion: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3196

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that it's not possible to use ts-node directly for that.

One option would be to switch to webpack, as it will support .ts extension in imports, but it does not perfectly replace ts-node as it's only for transpilation.

Globally, as I understand your goal, I will suggest you to have a look at https://www.edgedb.com/blog/how-we-converted-our-node-js-library-to-deno-using-deno and see if it helps (you'll need some extra work).